# Linear mapping on the vector space of sets with the symmetric difference

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am trying to construct a nice pedagogical example for a lecture. The power set of a finite set together with the symmetric difference (and scalar multiplication with $\mathbb F_2$) is a vector space. I would like to find a linear mapping on this set, but I am struggling to find one. For example, the "count operator" $\#$ is not linear, because $\#(\{1,2\} \triangle \{2,3\}) = \#(\{1,3\}) = 2$ which is not equal to $\#(\{1,2\}) + \#(\{2,3\})$.

Comment: do you want an endomorphism?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{F}_2$? Trivial examples are $x\mapsto 0$, and the identity.

Comment: @Riquelme: Not important, either an endomorphism, but I would also be fine with a linear mapping into $\mathbb R$ or any other vector space.

Comment: @Idontgetit: $\mathbb F_2$ is the finite field, i.e. $0+1 = 1$ but $1+1 = 0$. And I'd like to have a nontrivial example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example for an endomorphism is intersection.

Let $(\mathbb{V},\mathbb{F}_2)$ be the described vector space.
Let $F\subset \mathbb{V}$ and define $L:\mathbb{V}\rightarrow\mathbb{V}$ as $E\mapsto E\cap F$.
For any $A,B\in\mathbb{V}$, we have $L(A\Delta B)=A\Delta B\cap F = (A\cap F) \Delta (B\cap F)=L( A) \Delta L (B)$.
Now consider $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_2$.
If $\alpha=0$ and $E\in\mathbb{V}$,
$$
L(\alpha E)=L(\emptyset)=\emptyset\cap F=\emptyset = 0 E\cap F=\alpha L(E)
$$
If $\alpha=1$,
$$
L(\alpha E)=L(E)=E\cap F=1 E \cap F =\alpha L(E)
$$